# QPainter::drawLine has problem in Large image's width

Tags: c++, qt5, qpainter, qpixmap

Recently, I had a problem in my application (So I provided a mini example of the problem) that I faced when creating large-scale images, and when I looked at the output image, it was not fully drawn! I don't know why, so I created a mini-example of that.

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPixmap>

static QPixmap imageTest(int width, int height, QColor const &color) {
  static constexpr auto VERTICAL_PADDING = 2;
  QPixmap pixmap(width, height);
  pixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);

  QPainter painter(&pixmap);
  painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

  QPen pen(color);
  double const widthF = 1.0;
  pen.setWidthF(widthF);
  painter.setPen(pen);
  for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i) {
    QPointF p1(i, 94.9445); // mini example assume fixed height
    QPointF p2(i, 167.055); // mini example consider fixed height
    painter.drawLine(p1, p2);
  }
  painter.end();
  return pixmap;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
  auto image = imageTest(211'459, 262, Qt::GlobalColor::green);
  image.save("testFile.png", "PNG");
  app.quit();
  return 0;
}
```

the result of image , is something like this:

[image]

I also  tested that with other approaches, like drawLines and fillRect, but it didn't help me. What's the problem?

Comment: From what I recall, a `QPixmap`'s dimensions are limited to 32767 pixels in each direction.  Try using a `QImage` instead.

Comment: @G.M Thanks for that , but it does not help with QImage, so how I can create bigger image? I mean how solve this problem?

Comment: and Also I didnt find any limitation size in documents.

Comment: maybe only tile-base rendering can be solution ... Im not sure , cause of that asked that question.